# Index in custom selectors not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my code defining a new custom selector group.

```
(function($) {
    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
        group: function(element, index, matches, set) {
            var num = parseInt(matches[3], 10);

            if (isNaN(num)) {
                return false;
            } 

            console.log('The value of index element is '+index);

            return index%(num * 2)<num;
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Then in my `document.ready(function(){ });` when I call a simple

```
$('tr:group(3)')
```

The console.log says the following -->

```
`83` The value of index element is 0
```

This means that the index is constantly 0 and I am unable to know why.Any help will be appreciated.

**Please Check the following FIDDLE**  http://jsfiddle.net/hardeepmehta/KkTQX/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of jQuery are you running? In [this fiddle with 1.7.2](http://jsfiddle.net/z5XDR/1/), it returns non-zero indices, but [starting with 1.8.3](http://jsfiddle.net/z5XDR/2/), the indices are all zero.

In jQuery 1.8 and newer, you should use the [new Sizzle API for creating custom selectors](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation#sizzleselectorscreatepseudofunction).

The example they give:

```
Sizzle.selectors.pseudos.not =
Sizzle.selectors.createPseudo(function( selector /* the argument for not */ ) {
    var matcher = Sizzle.compile( selector );
    return function( elem ) {
        return !matcher( elem );
    };
});
```

Comment: I am using jQuery 1.9.0 which includes Sizzle.js.

Comment: Good point, canon. I didn’t think of that because the fiddles aren’t about that code at all.

Comment: Hey Guys Please check the Fiddle I've uploaded,
http://jsfiddle.net/hardeepmehta/KkTQX/

Check your console to see the not updating index value.

Comment: Like I said in my answer, your Fiddle is using the old API for custom pseudos, which is apparently not working after jQuery 1.83